# Filter through selected category with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building this search below, the `text-search` and the `filter by buttons` is working. My problem is how I can use the `input-field` to filter through the selected categories if the user has selected on category.

I've used the `:visible` selector.  If I use the `:visible` selector the search is not updating for example if the user hits `backspace` or makes typo, the search is not updating.

I've spent most of my day trying to make this work but with no good results.

can anyone help me with this?  here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/vqwcbr0g/19/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function(){
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem").filter(function(){
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

var btns = $('.filter-button').click(function(){
  if($(this).data('name') == 'all'){
    $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem').fadeIn(450);
  }else{
     var name = $(this).data('name');
           $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem.search-results-box-item').each(function(i, obj) {
               var names = $(obj).data('name').split(/\s*,\s*/);
               if($.inArray(name,names) === -1)
                   $(obj).hide();
               else
                   $(obj).show();
           });

       }
       btns.removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');

   })

})
```

```css
.service-boxes-centered li {
    min-width: 100px;
    padding-top: .8em;
    padding-bottom: .8em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    font-size: .9em;
    margin: .3em;
    color: #4b4b4b;
    text-decoration: none;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.service-box-item {
    border: 1px solid #979797;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.search-results-box-item {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.service-box-item.filter-button.active{
  border: red 1px solid !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container form-container">
  <div class="row search-form-item">

    <div class="col-md-12 searchtext-input">
    <h3>search by size: </h3>
  <label for="searchInput" class="sr-only">Search field</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" type="text">
    <div class="row service-boxes-centered">
     <ul>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button active" data-name="all">All</li>
      <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XS">XS</li>
      <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="S">S</li>
      <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="M">M</li>
      <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="L">L</li>
      <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XL">XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="2XL">2XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="3XL">3XL</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container" id="searchFilterDiv">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, XL, S, 2XL">
          <h3>flipside</h3>
            <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
            <p>M</p>
            <p>XL</p>
            <p>S</p>
            <p>2XL</p>
  <br>

    </div>
    
     <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, S">
          <h3>frontside</h3>
            <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
            <p>M</p>
            <p>S</p>
            
  <br>

    </div>
    
     <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="3XL">
          <h3>leftside</h3>
            <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
            <p>3XL</p>
            
            
  <br>

    </div>


      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem:visible").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  var btns = $('.filter-button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('name') == 'all') {
      $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem.search-results-box-item').each(function(i, obj) {
        var names = $(obj).data('name').split(/\s*,\s*/);
        if ($.inArray(name, names) === -1)
          $(obj).hide();
        else
          $(obj).show();
      });

    }
    btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

  })

})
```

```css
.service-boxes-centered li {
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-top: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .8em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: .3em;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.service-box-item {
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-results-box-item {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.service-box-item.filter-button.active {
  border: red 1px solid !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container form-container">
  <div class="row search-form-item">

    <div class="col-md-12 searchtext-input">
      <h3>search by size: </h3>
      <label for="searchInput" class="sr-only">Search field</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" type="text">
      <div class="row service-boxes-centered">
        <ul>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button active" data-name="all">All</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XS">XS</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="S">S</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="M">M</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="L">L</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XL">XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="2XL">2XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="3XL">3XL</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container" id="searchFilterDiv">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, XL, S, 2XL">
        <h3>flipside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>M</p>
        <p>XL</p>
        <p>S</p>
        <p>2XL</p>
        <br>

      </div>

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, S">
        <h3>frontside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>M</p>
        <p>S</p>

        <br>

      </div>

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="3XL">
        <h3>leftside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>3XL</p>


        <br>

      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**

Full Working Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem.visible").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  var btns = $('.filter-button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('name') == 'all') {
      $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem').addClass('visible').fadeIn(450);
    } else {
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      $('#searchFilterDiv div.SearchItem.search-results-box-item').each(function(i, obj) {
        var names = $(obj).data('name').split(/\s*,\s*/);
        if ($.inArray(name, names) === -1)
          $(obj).removeClass('visible').hide();
        else
          $(obj).addClass('visible').show();
      });

    }
    btns.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

  })

})
```

```css
.service-boxes-centered li {
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-top: .8em;
  padding-bottom: .8em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: .3em;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.service-box-item {
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.search-results-box-item {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.service-box-item.filter-button.active {
  border: red 1px solid !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container form-container">
  <div class="row search-form-item">

    <div class="col-md-12 searchtext-input">
      <h3>search by size: </h3>
      <label for="searchInput" class="sr-only">Search field</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="searchInput" type="text">
      <div class="row service-boxes-centered">
        <ul>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button active" data-name="all">All</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XS">XS</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="S">S</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="M">M</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="L">L</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="XL">XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="2XL">2XL</li>
          <li class=" service-box-item filter-button" data-name="3XL">3XL</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container" id="searchFilterDiv">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item visible" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, XL, S, 2XL">
        <h3>flipside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>M</p>
        <p>XL</p>
        <p>S</p>
        <p>2XL</p>
        <br>

      </div>

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item visible" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="M, S">
        <h3>frontside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>M</p>
        <p>S</p>

        <br>

      </div>

      <div class="SearchItem search-results-box-item visible" style="padding-bottom: 2em; display: block;" data-name="3XL">
        <h3>leftside</h3>
        <p>Vivamus viverra libero sed mi vehicula euismod. Nullam mauris dolor, hendrerit non lorem nec, vehicula dapibus nisl. In posuere est lectus, consequat tempus velit laoreet ut.</p>
        <p>3XL</p>


        <br>

      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I should have mention it in my question, but I have tried to use it... It works but if the user decides to hit backspace in the input-field  the search is not updating